# Django Multiple Foreign key set_all in template

Tags: python, django

I have two apps. one `customer` and another `xyz`. in my `xyz` app, I have 4 models. `Country,States,Cities & Shops`. In my Customer app, I have one model `Customers`.

MY Customers Model

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shops)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    uuid = UUIDField(auto=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    state = models.ForeignKey(States)
    city = models.ForeignKey(Cities)
```

My View

```
def edit_customer(request,uuid):
    current_customer = Customers.objects.filter(uuid=uuid,deleted=0)
    return render_to_response('customers/edit_customer.html',{'current_customer':current_customer},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm tried this in template. but, nothing found.

```
{% for customer in current_customer %}  

    {% for cn in customer.country_set.all %}
        <li>{{ cn.name }} </li>
        <li>{{ cn.id }} </li>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for st in customer.states_set.all %}
        <li>{{ st.name }} </li>
        <li>{{ st.id }} </li>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for ct in customer.cities_set.all %}
        <li>{{ ct.name }} </li>
        <li>{{ ct.id }} </li>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

What is the correct method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do it the other way round. As the django documentation states:

> Django also creates API accessors for the “other” side of the relationship – the link from the related model to the model that defines the relationship. For example, a Blog object b has access to a list of all related Entry objects via the entry_set attribute: b.entry_set.all().

Notice `the "other" side`.

So in your case you can do `state.customer_set.all()`. But looking at what you are trying to achieve I guess you are using the wrong field type, If you want the `customer` to be able to choose multiple location you should instead use `ManyToManyField`.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shops)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    uuid = UUIDField(auto=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    states = models.ManyToManyField(States)
    cities = models.ManyToManyField(Cities)
```

and then you can do something like `customer.countries.all()` or `customer.states.all()` or `customer.cities.all()`

**Update: Adding data to `ManyToManyField`:**

To add data to `ManyToManyField`'s you can do something like this:

```
customer = Customer(shop_id=shop_id, name=name)
customer.save()

# Add ManyToMany's
custome.states.add(state)
customer.cities.add(cities)
customer.countries.add(country)
```

I would also suggest you to go through the django documentation for [`ManyToManyFields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: I'm currently insert customer data like this. Now I'm changed my fields to manytomany. so I cant Insert countr,state & city like this. How to insert customer data in customers_countries table. c = Customers(shop_id=shop_id,name=name, country=country , state=state, city=city)
c.save()